# Regular Expression for specific number of special character in Swift

Tags: swift, regex

I have a string like

```
start tcp connect
1\'s time=46ms, 2\'s time=14ms, 3\'s time=10ms, 4\'s time=24ms, 5\'s time=10ms, average=20ms
start tcp connect end
ping: XXX.XXX.com start
64 bytes from 111.111.111.111 icmp_seq=#0 type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=10ms
64 bytes from 111.111.111.111 icmp_seq=#1 type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=10ms
64 bytes from 111.111.111.111 icmp_seq=#2 type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=34ms
ping: XXX.XXX.com end
```

I want to get the millisecond from this string 
This result like [10,10,34]

I try to use

> 64 bytes from \d+.\d+.\d+.\d+ icmp_seq=#\d+
>   type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=(\d+)ms

but get whole string array
["64 bytes from 122.51.224.87 icmp_seq=#0 type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=10ms" , ....]

Comment: you can try with regex `(\d{2})(?=ms$)`

Comment: How many digits your icmp_seq might have?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `all` is a string containing the entire body of text you're showing, this will work:

```
let values = all
    .split(separator: "\n")
    .filter { $0.hasPrefix("64 bytes from") }
    .map { (substring: Substring) -> Substring in
        let start = substring.range(of: "time=")!
        let end = substring.range(of: "ms")!
        return substring[start.upperBound..<end.lowerBound]
    }
    .map { Int($0)! }
```

`values` would then be the array of integers: `[10, 10, 34]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pattern to find any number of digits `\d+` between two strings using look behind `(?<=)` and look ahead `(?=)` creating a regular expression like `(?<=64 bytes from \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3} icmp_seq=#\d{1} type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=)\d+(?=ms)` and search your string while you find a match:

```
func getTimes(from string: String) -> [Int] {
    let pattern = #"(?<=64 bytes from \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3} icmp_seq=#\d{1} type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=)\d+(?=ms)"#
    var times: [Int] = []
    var startIndex = string.startIndex
    while let range = string[startIndex...].range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
        times.append(Int(string[range])!)
        startIndex = range.upperBound
    }
    return times
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let string = """
start tcp connect
1\'s time=46ms, 2\'s time=14ms, 3\'s time=10ms, 4\'s time=24ms, 5\'s time=10ms, average=20ms
start tcp connect end
ping: XXX.XXX.com start
64 bytes from 111.111.111.111 icmp_seq=#0 type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=10ms
64 bytes from 111.111.111.111 icmp_seq=#1 type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=10ms
64 bytes from 111.111.111.111 icmp_seq=#2 type=ICMPv4TypeEchoReply time=34ms
ping: XXX.XXX.com end
"""

let times = getTimes(from: string)
print(times)  // "[10, 10, 34]\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture group for the digits. Thus:

```
let results = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"Reply time=(\d+)ms"#)
    .matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
    .compactMap { $0.range(at: 1) }
    .compactMap { Range($0, in: string) }
    .compactMap { Int(string[$0]) }
```

Now, I’m using `\d+`, to match any sequence of one or more digits. But if you wanted to match a certain number of digits, say between one and three digits only, you could use `\d{1,3}`. But in this case, I’m not sure why you’d want to limit it to a specific number of digits (e.g. do you really want to exclude numbers greater than `999`?). But the `{` and `}` with the minimum and maximum number of occurrences is how you would specify the number of the digits.